# Probability of event happening

Tags: probability, statistics

It has been very long since i last did any maths and my background is somewhat spotty in maths, so forgive me for perhaps asking a basic question, i would very much appreciate any help i could be offered.

**Problem**:
I have a large data set which looks like this:

```
        True_False  cum_val
Date        
2018-01-02  False   NaN
2018-01-03  False   0.006399
2018-01-04  False   0.010427
2018-01-05  False   0.017461
2018-01-08  False   0.019124
2018-01-09  False   0.020426
2018-01-10  False   0.019314
2018-01-11  False   0.026348
2018-01-12  False   0.033098
2018-01-16  False   0.029573
2018-01-17  False   0.038988
2018-01-18  False   0.037372
2018-01-19  False   0.041757
2018-01-22  False   0.049824
2018-01-23  False   0.051998
2018-01-24  False   0.051438
2018-01-25  False   0.052041
2018-01-26  False   0.063882
2018-01-29  False   0.057150
2018-01-30  True    -0.010899
2018-01-31  True    -0.010410
2018-02-01  True    -0.011058
2018-02-02  True    -0.032266
2018-02-05  True    -0.073246
2018-02-06  True    -0.055805
2018-02-07  True    -0.060806
2018-02-08  True    -0.098343
2018-02-09  True    -0.083407
2018-02-12  False   0.013915
2018-02-13  False   0.016528
2018-02-14  False   0.029930
2018-02-15  False   0.041999
2018-02-16  False   0.042373
2018-02-20  False   0.036531
2018-02-21  False   0.031035
2018-03-06  False   0.013671
```

I need to create a statistical model which can answer this question: What is the probability that when `False` toggles to `True`, that there is a successive probability of 2nd, 3rd, 4th and so on `True` value?

I am looking for someone to point me to the general direction, perhaps a theorem or something which will give me a starting point.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you perhaps have some more context? What kind of data is it? Do you already know or suspect some structure in the data? For example: what does the third column stand for? Do successive data points depend on each other somehow?

Comment: This is a stock data, I have some conditions under which the bool True and False is generated. There is a high probability that True will repeat again but there are times it does not. I wanted to what is the probability that True will repeat again! Please ignore the third column. I would venture a guess and say this is not an independent event since we start counting from True

Answer (score 1):

If you think of the lengths of "runs" of consecutive True values in your data set as samples of a random variable $X$, then a natural estimate for $P(X\ge k)$ is $\frac{\text{number of runs seen of length $\ge k$}}{\text{total number of runs seen}}$.

Alternatively, if you have more information about the underlying process that produces these values, you can model that process and use [Bayesian inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference) to find parameters for the model that best fit your data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably not understanding what you're asking, but I'll give it a try. It looks like you want,for each $n \in \{2, 3, \ldots\}$, the probability of seeing a run of $n$ True values in the next $n$ days (including today), given that today is True and yesterday was False. Call that event $R_n$. If we rely on the table $\textbf{only}$, then this is just a matter of counting occurrences. For example, for $n = 2$, let $TF$ denote the True_False column, add two columns to the table: $Toggle$ and $Run_2$, and set the value on row $i$ as follow:
$$Toggle[i] = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if} \ TF[i] = \text{True and } \ TF[i-1] = \text{False} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
$$Run_2[i] = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if} \ TF[i] = TF[i-1] = \text{True and } TF[i-2] = \text{False} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
then:
$$P(R_2) = \frac{\sum{Run_2[i]}}{\sum Toggle[i]}$$
And similarly for other values of $n$.

Comment: I meant excluding today, if it toggles `True` today than successive `Trues` after today. Since the event starts at `True`. Thanks

Comment: That only requires a slight change in notation: What I call $R_n$ is $R_{n-1}$ for you. Same approach. Is my "solution" even close to what you're looking for?

Comment: Give me some time to meditate on this

Comment: I must add that a smarter way of doing this would be to infer the probability distribution of the True/False values and then use it to deduce in a purely mathematical way (that is, no longer looking at the data) the probabilities in question. That requires more advanced techniques (which I don't know).